# Получить количество элементов из другого класса

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с проблемой, в одном классе когда заполняю список и вывожу его мне показует что в списке есть элементы. Но когда я хочу узнать количество этих элементов в другом классе, то мне показует что список пуст. Как решить эту проблему?

**Класс 1**

```
class Car
{
    private string name { get; set; }
    private string color { get; set; }
    private int speed { get; set; }
    private int year { get; set; }
    protected List<Car> spisok { get; set; } = new List<Car>();

    public void Buy()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите названия машины ->");
            name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите цвет машины ->");
            color = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите скорость машины ->");
            speed = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите год випуска машины ->");
            year = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            spisok.Add(new Car() { name = name, color = color, speed = speed, year = year });
        }
        //foreach(Car i in spisok)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(i);
        //}
    }
```

**Класс 2**

```
class Garage:Car
{
    public void Delete()
    {
        foreach (Car i in spisok)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

    }
    public void Drive()
    {

    }
}
```

**Main**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car car = new Car();
            Garage garage = new Garage();
            car.Buy();
            garage.Delete();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spisok` в "Класс 1" и `spisok` в "Класс 2" - это разные списки.

---

Случай тяжелый. Класс `Car` не должен содержать список объектов `Car`. А гараж не может наследовать от машины, потому что машиной не является. Тем не менее, покажите, как Вы вызываете методы `Buy` и `Delete`.

---

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Garage garage = new Garage();
   garage.Buy();
   garage.Delete();
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Нет, один и тот же список

Comment: @Key Нет, разные.

Comment: А не так понял, простите. То-есть получается что когда я вызываю этот список в классе 2, то это получается новый список?

Comment: Хорошо, а как сделать чтобы это было не два разных списка, если я вызываю список в 2 классе через наследования из 1 класса?

Comment: @Key Я, конечно, о многом могу догадаться, но правильнее все-таки будет показать Ваш код.

Comment: Сейчас исправлю вопрос и там покажу код

Comment: Исправил, вставил код из main

Comment: Помогла, но все равно класс Garage наследуется от Car, так как нужно же получить доступ к полям класса Car

Comment: @Key К каким полям? Они у Вас все `private`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115777/discussion-between-key-and-igor).

Comment: Сори, тупанул немного. Да вы прави